# typeof window.close is different for IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Today I saw weird behavior 
 when I typed `window.close`  it showing `function close() {     [native code] }` in IE and `function () { [native code] }` in chrome, I thought both are function.

But when I typed `typeof(window.close)` it showing `'object'` in IE8 and `'function'` in chrome.

Why this different behavior? 
What are the ways I can use to check type of a variable in JavaScript?
Is there other functions which shows this type of behavior?

Thanks

Comment: For checking if a value is a function, use `something instanceof Function`, but only if `typeof(something)!=='undefined'`.

Comment: @Jay window.close instanceof Function is false for IE8.

Comment: I think `window.close` in IE has broken implementation. While `String(window.close)==='function close() { [native code] }'`, it doesn't have `apply` nor `prototype` members.

Comment: It's the same situation for `window.confirm` :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) for what you should have (ie `"function"`).

And [here](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.4.3) for the less readable but official ECMAScript reference.

IE 8 simply doesn't follow the norm. That's really not the sole occurrence.

Regarding the *How to test if a variable is a function on IE8 ?* question, I can't test it myself but this probably works :

```
var myvar = window.close;
var isfunc = Object.prototype.toString.call( myvar ) === '[object Function]';
```